# Torch installed but repeat_interleave not found

Tags: python, pytorch

I have PyTorch installed.
`import torch` runs without error. However, the function [`torch.repeat_interleave()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.repeat_interleave.html#torch.repeat_interleave) is not found:

```py
x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])
x.repeat_interleave(2)
```

gives `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'repeat_interleave'`

Why?

Comment: What is the `torch.__version__` value?

Comment: The value is '0.4.1'

Comment: But I just installed PyTorch, why does conda install an old version for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `torch.repeat_interleave` operator was introduced in `1.1.0` release of `pytorch`, so please, consider updating to `1.1.0+` version of `pytorch` to use this method smoothly.